# How to use whereNotNull in controller while using with (' Many-to-many relationships') to show on the blade view?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, foreign-keys, laravel-query-builder

I try to show the 'categories' from **Many to Many relationships** and use
**whereNotNull** at the same time but when I use **whereNotNull** to check that the users have approved then the **categories** from the **relationships** are disappeared in the blade view.

If I have not put whereNotNull. The list of users who are vendors still appears (approved and waiting for approval both of them are showing in the view with the category relationships). When I use whereNotNull the blade view will show only approved users without category relationships.

**The explanation pictures.**

> [When use whereNotNull click!](https://www.234.in.th/images/2020/12/24/1f0ec6e871b484f9f.png)

> [When not use whereNotNull click!](https://www.234.in.th/images/2020/12/24/2.png)

**This is the view that I want to show the categories from the relationships.**

```xml
@if(count($user->categories) > 0)
     @foreach ($user->categories as $category)
       <span class="badge badge-pill badge-info p-2 m-1">{{ $category->name }}</span>
     @endforeach
@endif
```

**The UserController**

```php
public function index()
{
    $users = User::with('categories') // Eager loading
        ->where('role', 'vendor')
        ->whereNotNull('approved_at')     //If I put whereNotNull the categories will now showing
        ->get();                            but If I delete it, the relationships will appear in the 
                                             view again.
    return view('admin.vendorDashboard')
        ->with('categories', Categories::all())
        ->with('users', $users);
    }
}
```

**User Model**

```php
public function categories()
{
    return $this->BelongsToMany(Categories::class);
}
```

**Categories Model**

```php
public function users()
{
    return $this->BelongsToMany(User::class);
}
```

**User Table**

| Id | User | Approved_at | Role |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 2020-12-24 18:40:59 | Vendor |
| 2 | B | 2020-12-24 18:39:59 | Vendor |

**Category Table**

| Id | Category |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | C |
| 2 | D |

**user_category table**

| Id | user_id | category_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 2 |

Thank you in advance.

p.s. sorry for my bad English.

Comment: `approved_at` is a field from `Users` table ?

Comment: yes, sir. that's correct.

Comment: The query won't return `Users` who are not approved and the `categories` of those users wont be returned either. What's the problem then ?

Comment: If I have not put whereNotNull. The list of users who are vendors still appears (approved and waiting for approval both of them are showing in the view with the category relationships). When I use whereNotNull the blade view will show only approved users without category relationships.

Comment: shouldn't it be `$category->category` in your view?

Comment: please see my explanation pictures
https://www.234.in.th/images/2020/12/24/1f0ec6e871b484f9f.png   (when use whereNotNull)

Comment: https://www.234.in.th/images/2020/12/24/2.png (when not use whereNotNull)